# dataset for 13F/13G SEC filing

Tags: quandl, edgar

I am looking for a database that contains the 13F/13G filings in Quandl but can't find any.
Maybe I am not using the right keywords?
Any suggestion where to find a curated dataset? I don't want to end up scraping EDGAR again.
Cheers!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

I've been downloading [these free curated data sets of Form 13F](https://sites.google.com/view/sec-form-13f-data-sets/) available as CSV, XLS, and JSON. They're formatted to be immediately analyzable.